# Identify location using images technologies

Tags: google-maps, image-processing, google-api

I want to identify location using the location image.Is there any google api to support to do this?.or any technology?.Thankz for any help

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for. Can you give an example ? Do you want to get a location (place name/ city/ street name) by giving an image (georeferenced or not??) etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean is there any way to upload an image and have Google detect where that location is, no, there isn't a Google technology, or any other that I'm aware of that would do that.